# Find R-square value of Weibull fit (Survival model) in R

Tags: r, weibull, goodness-of-fit, survival

I have a survival object (S) for which I am doing a weibull fit using the survreg function and weibull distribution in R.

```
S = Surv(data$ValueX, data$ValueY)
W = Survreg(S ~ 1, data=data, dist="weibull")
```

How do I extract the R-square value of the Weibull fit which is essentially a linear line? Or is there a function to calculate the correlation coefficient value Rho?

Basically, I want to calculate the goodness of fit.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But what do you want the r-squared value for? What two sets of values are you comparing?

Comment: Sure, Will do next time! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `pam.censor` in the PAmeasures package which produces an R^2 like statistic. Using the ovarian dataset from the survival package:

```
library(PAmeasures)
library(survival)

fit.s <- survreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, data = ovarian, dist="weibull" )
p <- predict(fit.s, type = "response")
with(ovarian, pam.censor(futime, p, fustat))
```

For the ovarian data with an age regressor we get a value of only 0.0915 .

Another idea is that for a Weibull model with no covariates we have S(t) = exp(- (lambda * t)^p) so log(-log(S(t))) is linear in log(t) hence we could use the R squared of the corresponding regression to measure how well the model fits to a Weibull.

```
library(survival)

fit1 <- survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ 1, data = ovarian)
sum1 <- summary(fit1, times = ovarian$futime)
fo <- log(-log(surv)) ~ log(time)
d <- as.data.frame(sum1[c("time", "surv")])
fit.lm <- lm(fo, d)
summary(fit.lm)$r.sq

plot(fo, d)
abline(fit.lm)
```

For the ovarian data without covariates the R^2 at 93% is high but the plot does suggest systematic departures from linearity so it may not really be Weibull.

### Other

Not sure if this is of interest but the eha package has the `check.dist` function which can be used for a visual comparison of a parametric baseline hazard model to a cox proportional hazard model.  See the documentation as well as:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5233524/

Using the ovarian dataset from survival:

```
library(eha)
library(surival)

fit.c <- coxreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, data = ovarian)
fit.p <- phreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age, data = ovarian, dist = "weibull")
check.dist(fit.c, fit.p)
```

The survAUC package has three functions that provide r squared type statistics for cox proportional hazard models (`OXS`, `Nagelk` and `XO`).

Comment: The method to use corresponding regression model worked very well! Thank you. Like you mentioned in your comment, the PAMeasures package didn't really reflect the right fit. I also tried the eha package but I wanted a numeric measure more than visual. But it is useful to know! Thanks again.